# Predict score based on rotated PCA

Tags: pca, predictive-models, factor-rotation, rotation

I have done a varimax rotated PCA on my "test" dataset. I would like to use this PCA (i.e. the varimax rotated PCA) on a new dataset and predict the scores. This function `predicted<-predict(PCA_test_data,new_data)` doesn't allow me to do this because it doesn't incorporate the rotation step. `PCA_test_data` refers to the unrotated PCA.

Any ideas how to predict scores based on a varimax rotated pca???

Comment: Most PCA packages allow users to output the coefficients associated with each variable-component combination. These coefficients can be used in scoring new data.

Comment: The answer is software-specific, so flag your software (R?).